# How to give animation to FloatingActionButton in android studio

Tags: android-layout, animation, android-studio, floating-action-button

I am giving Animation to `FloatingActionButton` to Move Right Side Position to Left Side. For that I am Implementing below Code. But That Don't Work. And I also Want to Change the icon of `FloatingActionButton` When I click on it.

**Java Code :**

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(400.0f,200.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
                animation.setDuration(5000);
                animation.setRepeatCount(1);
                animation.setRepeatMode(1);
                fab.startAnimation(animation);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Use `FlotingActionMenu`..!!

Comment: @janki gadhiya Is there any Library or sample project is there provide the link if yes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this library I solve my Problem.

https://github.com/shell-software/fab

**Step 1 :** you have to put this dependency in your build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.shell-software:fab:1.1.2'
}
```

**Step 2 :** write this in your xml file.

```
 <com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton 
            android:id="@+id/action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            />
```

**Step : 3** Intialize the ActionButton

```
ActionButton actionButton = (ActionButton) findViewById(R.id.action_button);
```

**Step : 4** Apply different effect for your different purpose.

**1. Moving ActionButton**

```
int distance = 100.0f // in density-independent pixels

// Move ActionButton left
actionButton.moveLeft(distance);
```

**2. Button types**

There are three types of Action Button, which you can work with:

- DEFAULT (56dp)
- MINI (40dp)
- BIG (72dp)

**3. Button size**

To work with ActionButton size use:

```
// To get the ActionButton size
float size = actionButton.getSize();

// To set the ActionButton size
actionButton.setSize(60.0f); //
```

**4. Button states**

There are two button states, which Action Button may reside in:

- NORMAL
- PRESSED

**5. Button colors**

Button colors can be set as for the NORMAL state, so for the PRESSED one. By default the following colors are set:

```
 #FF9B9B9B for the NORMAL state
 #FF696969 for the PRESSED state
```

**6. Shadow**

Shadow can be customized in three ways: color, radius and offset. By default shadow enabled and has the following default values:

- shadowColor = #42000000 (~ light-grey)
- shadowRadius = 8.0f (in density-independent pixels)
- shadowXOffset = 0.0f (in density-independent pixels)
- shadowYOffset = 8.0f (in density-independent pixels)

**7. Image**

you can change actionButton Image using following code.

```
actionButton.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
actionButton.setImageDrawable(getResource.getDrawable(R.drawable.fab_plus_icon));
actionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.fab_plus_icon);
```

**8. Stroke**

Stroke can be customized in two ways: width and the color. Stroke disabled by default, however it has the default values:

- strokeColor = Color.BLACK
- strokeWidth = 0.0f (no stroke)

### InShort

In Xml you directly define the all thing

xml for that is :

```
<com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton 
            android:id="@+id/action_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
            fab:type="DEFAULT"
            fab:button_color="@color/fab_material_lime_500"
            fab:button_colorPressed="@color/fab_material_lime_900"
            fab:image="@drawable/fab_plus_icon"
            fab:image_size="24dp"
            fab:shadow_color="#757575"
            fab:shadow_radius="1.0dp"
            fab:shadow_xOffset="0.5dp"
            fab:shadow_yOffset="1.0dp"
            fab:stroke_color="@color/fab_material_blue_grey_500"
            fab:stroke_width="1.0dp"
            fab:button_colorRipple="@color/fab_material_black"
            fab:rippleEffect_enabled="false"
            fab:shadowResponsiveEffect_enabled="true"
            fab:show_animation="@anim/fab_roll_from_down"
            fab:hide_animation="@anim/fab_roll_to_down"
            />
```